# Is it possible to access my files on a computer without logging in?

Tags: files

I am a total noob and I screwed up Ubuntu 13.04 AMD64 file permissions royally. Currently I cannot log in nor can I access anything useful from Guest.  Since 13.10 is imminent, I'd like to transfer all my docs, media, etc., to a whole new installation. How can I do that?

Comment: Why you can't log in?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a live cd or usb (or an other computer to create one) you can use it to recover your documents: choose the `try before installing` option go to the file manager, under devices go into your hard drive and copy your files to a usb stick or external hdd.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Wouter mentioned in his answer you can replace your current Ubuntu version with 13.10. Once you've copied your files to an external hdd or basically have them copied somewhere safe, you can use 13.10's LiveCD and choose to replace 13.04 with it.

If this is something that you want to do, you'll have to wait for a couple of days though, 13.10 is launched on the 17th of this month.